# no password_confirmation on create but need it during update (authlogic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I am quite new to rails and I am using authlogic for my authentication system. I want to have password_confirmation when user updates his profile, but not when he is signing up.

I figured out this config option

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.require_password_confirmation=false
end
```

When I do this, it ignores password_confirmation during signup (which is fine) but while editing user profile, I want it to consider password_confirmation field. is there any method I can configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have suspended the Authlogic based validation you can achieve this with a standard Rails model validation such as:

```
validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :if => :password_required?
```

where the `password_required?` is an optional model method, which tests if you want this validation for a given scenario.

**UPDATE**

As it seems that the `c.require_password_confirmation=false` option means the `password_confirmation` attribute is no longer automatically created then you need to approach the solution slightly differently. Create a virtual attribute manually and a custom validation for the specific case of profile updates. Something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation

  validate do |user|
    unless user.new_record?
      user.errors.add :password, "is required" if self.password.blank?
      user.errors.add :password_confirmation, "is required" if self.password_confirmation.blank?
      user.errors.add_to_base, "Password and confirmation must match" if self.password != self.password_confirmation
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: when I do c.require_password_confirmation=false the password_confirmation field is completely not available to the controller & views, forget about validating... is there any way i can make it available? it throws this error "undefined method `password_confirmation' for #<User" (as it is not available)

Comment: @Madhusudhan I've updated the response with an additional suggested approach to deal with this.